# What kind of small/bonsai-tree is this pictured one?

Tags: identification, bonsai

Recently I moved to a new house and there was a bonsai tree that seems to be very weak.

What kind of bonsai tree is it?

[image]

Answer (score 10):

My first reflex was [Crassula ovata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crassula_ovata), aka. jade plant or money tree, but after taking a closer look, I now id it as **[Portulacaria afra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portulacaria_afra)**, the **dwarf jade plant**.

Both are succulent plants from southern Africa, looking quite similar on a first glance and both are popular bonsai plants. But the Crassula ovata has egg-shaped leaves , the Portulacaria afra more round to heart-shaped ones. Also, the latter tends to have more "ribbed" stems while the former is smooth.

Answer (score 7):

It appears much like a dwarf jade plant (Portulacaria afra); thick ovular leafs, segmented trunk and stems are all very jade-like. Portulacaria afra is a tropical plant that can and often is grown indoors. It can be propagated by simply breaking off a leaf and sticking it into damp soil. Crassula, known commonly as 'jade' tends to make thicker stems than the photographed plant.